# How can I convert a float in a str without losing significant figures?

Tags: python, string, number-formatting

I want to convert the number `0.054000` in a `str`, but when I write `srt(0.054000)` I get `'0.054'`. I need to get `'0.054000'`. How can I do it?

I have a data file with numbers as my example (0.054000). I need to count the digits of each number. I don't know how to read that number in a way that I count seven digits, for instance.

Comment: >>> a = 0.054
>>> "{:08f}".format(a)   gives   
'0.054000'

Comment: @DanPatterson shouldn't it be `"{:06f}".format(a)`?

Comment: should have used !r ...  >>> "{!r:<06}".format(a)   gives
'0.0540'  While   
>>> "{!r:<08}".format(a)
'0.054000'  !s doesnt worry as much

Comment: The float never tracked significant figures in the first place. If you want to retain that information, you'll need to track it yourself or find a library that does it.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Nicely representing a floating-point number in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663612/nicely-representing-a-floating-point-number-in-python), with the code from the accepted answer `f(0.0056, 5) -> '0.0056000'`

Comment: I have a data file with numbers as my example (0.054000). I need to count the digits of each number, so your idea doesn't work for me. I don't know how to read that number in a way that I count seven digits, for instance.

Comment: @DanielaAlzate: Read it as a string, then. Don't convert it to a float in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Dan Patterson's method is the only way to do it reliably - python makes no differentiation between .0054 and .054000: e.g.

```
>>> .0054 is .0054000
True
```

Thus you will probably have to simply specify the number of digits you have in sig figs, either using his method or `(str(.0054000) + "0"*number_of_sig_figs)`.

Comment: why would you ever use `(str(.0054000) + "000")` in actual code? That only adds 3 `0` at the end of the number, it has nothing to do with significant digits.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen That didn't make much sense, sorry. What I meant is that you would have to keep track of how many sig figs you have and just add those zeroes back on at the end.

Comment: but given that `.0054000` should have `5` significant digits how would you actually go about figuring out that you should add *3* extra zeros to the end?

Answer (score 0):

A **format specifier** starts with a colon and then may contain any of the terms shown
in brackets in the following (each of the terms is optional)

: [[fill]align] [sign] [#] [0] [width] [,] [.precision] [type]

A brief description of the [.precision] is provided below.

**.precision**: Maximum number of characters for strings (integer); number of digits of
precision for floats. For f, F, e, and E type specifiers this is the number
of digits to the right of the decimal point.

We can use this to specify the precision of our float value:

```
a=0.540000
print("{:06f}".format(a))
```

This gives the desired output:

```
0.540000
```

Hope this was helpful!